# Which bibtex style lists book editor first?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I've got a book in which the relevant citation is really the editor, not the original author:

```
@book{butler_frankenstein_1998,
address = {Oxford ; New York},
series = {Oxford world's classics},
title = {Frankenstein, or, {The} modern {Prometheus}: the 1818 text},
isbn = {978-0-19-283366-2},
shorttitle = {Frankenstein, or, {The} modern {Prometheus}},
publisher = {Oxford University Press},
author = {Shelley, Mary Wollstonecraft},
editor = {Butler, Marilyn},
year = {1998},
keywords = {Frankenstein, Victor, Frankenstein's Monster, Horror tales, Monsters, Science fiction, Scientists}
}
```

(This was exported from Zotero)

So far all the bibliography styles I've tried (abbrv, acm, apalike, plain,...) generally don't even list the editor at all, let alone put her first.

**Which bibliography style should I choose, or what modifications should I make, in order to get it to put the editor first**, e.g.:

> Butler, M. (ed.), M. W. Shelley, Frankenstein; or, The Modern
>   Prometheus: the 1818 text (Oxford University Press, 1998).

**or something similar?**

I'm using latex & bibtex, but I'm happy to switch to natbib, biblatex, whatever else, and/or download style files.  Just not sure what to do...

.

PS: Never used `makebst` before; intimidated, and anyway when I followed some instructions on [How to make your personal LaTeX bibliography style](http://chgarms.com/archives/87) I got:

```
$ latex makebst
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `makebst'.
<*> makebst

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
^D
$ sudo tlmgr install custom-bib
tlmgr install: package already present: custom-bib
$ ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use `biblatex`, `useauthor=false` might be what you are looking for. You can add this to the `options` field in the bib entry

```
@book{butler_frankenstein_1998,
  address    = {Oxford and New York},
  series     = {Oxford world's classics},
  title      = {Frankenstein, or, {The} modern {Prometheus}},
  subtitle   = {the 1818 text},
  isbn       = {978-0-19-283366-2},
  publisher  = {Oxford University Press},
  author     = {Shelley, Mary Wollstonecraft},
  editor     = {Butler, Marilyn},
  year       = {1998},
  options    = {useauthor=false},
}
```

With `style=authoryear` that gives

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{butler_frankenstein_1998,
  address    = {Oxford and New York},
  series     = {Oxford world's classics},
  title      = {Frankenstein, or, {The} modern {Prometheus}},
  subtitle   = {the 1818 text},
  isbn       = {978-0-19-283366-2},
  publisher  = {Oxford University Press},
  author     = {Shelley, Mary Wollstonecraft},
  editor     = {Butler, Marilyn},
  year       = {1998},
  options    = {useauthor=false},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{butler_frankenstein_1998}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks @moewe!  Took me a little while to get up to speed on biblatex, biber, etc, but now I'm reproducing your results, and along with adding "firstinits=true" in the \usepackage[]{biblatex} line, it gives me essentially what I need.

Comment: @sh37211 Well, it only took you about half an hour, so I guess you were quick to pick up the most important bits and pieces. The option `firstinits`  has been renamed to `giveninits`, so in newer versions of `biblatex` you want `giveninits=true`.